# inner join with group by expression in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, inner-join

I am new to sql, any help is appreciated.

I have two tables, `employees` and `jobs`. `employees` contain a variable `job_id` (multiple employees can have the same job_ID). `jobs` contain variables `job_id` and `job_title` (one job_ID correspond to one job_title, this is the hr schema in oracle if you are interested).

I want the query to return: the job_title, job_ID and the number of people who have the same job_Id.

I tried the following code:

```
select j.job_title, e.job_ID, count(e.job_ID)
from employees e, jobs j
where e.job_id=j.job_id
group by e.job_Id
```

the error message is:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 83 Column: 8

Can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading.  When you `select` a bunch of fields and an aggregate, you have to `group by` every field you `select` and only the fields you `select`. So your query has to be:

```sql
select j.job_title, e.job_ID, count(e.job_ID)
from employees e, jobs j
where e.job_id=j.job_id
group by e.job_Id, j.job_title
```