# SQL Query not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I seem to be getting this error while trying to run the below query:

```
SELECT 
to_char(EFFECTIVE_DT,'YYYY-MM') as YYYYMM,
--EFFECTIVE_DT,
AH01_PAYMENT_STATUS_CTD,
TSYS_ACCT_ID
FROM OIS_TSYS.AH_CYCLE_HIST 
WHERE 1=1
AND EFFECTIVE_DT BETWEEN '01-MAY-2017' AND '31-MAY-2017'
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 1
```

**error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression**

I am trying to group by date as at the moment i get the results daily for each individual account.

```
Result set:
65589   N   03-MAY-17
65590   S   03-MAY-17
65591   M   03-MAY-17
65592   F   03-MAY-17
65617   G   03-MAY-17
```

Any help be amazing.

Best,
Saad

Comment: Your result set doesn't match the query? Also, why are you grouping by 2? That means you're grouping by the literal value 2, meaning all rows will be in the group. It's a bit pointless\*. Especially since you don't have anything to aggregate - no count/max/min function is present. Perhaps you meant to distinct? \**Group by doesn't understand positional references to the selected columns, since it's calculated before the list of columns is considered.*

Comment: Group by 2
means, you group by the second column of the select statement

Comment: @EstebanP. - Oracle doesn't allow group by position. Only `order by` recognises that. (You can group by a column that isn't in the select list, for a start... though I suppose you can order by one too.)

Comment: @AlexPoole: thanks - didn't knew that - thought it will work
anyway: i would never use just the positionnumber of a column in a order by clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inner join with group by expression in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870331/inner-join-with-group-by-expression-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: You have no aggregating functions, and no posted attributes which look aggregatable,  so what exact output do you expect your query to produce?

Answer (score 0):

When you "group by 2", all other columns must have an aggregate function like (sum, avg, min, max,..)

The "1=1" is pretty useless

Comment: what do you expect as result?
why do you want to group your result?

remember: all columns, which are not in your group by clause, must have an aggregate-function like sum/avg/min/max

Comment: i want the result set to look like this     65589   N   MAY-17
65590   S   MAY-17
65591   M   MAY-17
65592   F   MAY-17
65617   G   MAY-17 (by month eg. May it gives me the number of accounts in S, then M, then F etc.)

Comment: when you group by date, you have to use an aggregate-function on the other columns like:
like:
MIN(AH01_PAYMENT_STATUS_CTD)
,MIN(TSYS_ACCT_ID)

Comment: brilliant understood...but what if TSYS_ACCT_ID is represented in S,M,F etc. as its values what can i use as an aggregate to keep those as is?

Comment: if you want to keep them how they are, just add TSYS_ACCT_ID to the "group by"
and you will receive a row for every occurance.
please try to solve basic problems, before posting them and waiting for a solution.
it looks like you are very new to SQL, so have a look on online documentations first:
in your example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result use the below query:
When you apply group by clause in any query you cannot just put one column in the group by clause if there are more than one colum in the select clause apart from the aggregate functions like sum, count, min, max etc. So in your case you have to put all the three columns in group by that you selected in the select clause.

```
    SELECT 
    TSYS_ACCT_ID,
    AH01_PAYMENT_STATUS_CTD,
    to_char(EFFECTIVE_DT,'YYYY-MM') as YYYYMM
    FROM OIS_TSYS.AH_CYCLE_HIST 
    WHERE EFFECTIVE_DT BETWEEN '01-MAY-2017' AND '31-MAY-2017'
    GROUP BY 
    TSYS_ACCT_ID,
    AH01_PAYMENT_STATUS_CTD,
    to_char(EFFECTIVE_DT,'YYYY-MM')
    ORDER BY 1
```